# Why is void B::f() const & chosen when B::f is called by a temporary object of B?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference, ref-qualifier

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void f() const &
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()&" << std::endl;
    }

    void f() const &&
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()&&" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    void f() const &
    {
        std::cout << "B::f()&" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A{}.f();
    B{}.f();
}
```

The output is:

> A::f()&&
>
> B::f()&

Note that `void B::f() const &&` doesn't exist.

To me, a temporary object of `B` calls `B::f`, `void B::f() const &&` should be chosen, or a compiler error should be raised.

**Why is `void B::f() const &` chosen in such a case?**

Comment: I think it is just because you simply don't have a `void f() const &&`, C++ seem to tend to allow you writing more flexible code than confining you to do micro optimizations manually.  This is similar to using the `Object(const Object &)` if calling it with `std::move(object)` if there is no move constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `void B::f() const &&` doesn't exist, the next best candidate is selected which is your `void B::f() const &`. The rvalue will bind to a `const &`. If you remove the const you will notice you will get a compile error as the rvalue cannot bind to a non-const reference. The example on [cppreference/overloadresolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) shows it perfectly.

```
int i;
int f1();
int g(const int&);  // overload #1
int g(const int&&); // overload #2
int j = g(i);    // lvalue int -> const int& is the only valid conversion
int k = g(f1()); // rvalue int -> const int&& better than rvalue int -> const int&
```

This is no different for the implicit `this` argument in your examples.

> To me, a temporary object of B calls B::f, void B::f() const && should be chosen, or a compiler error should be raised.

if this was the case then code like the [following](https://ideone.com/l9H1Q4) would break without a [const] rvalue reference overload existing.

```
void f(const int& i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
}
```